# Using Flutter Checkbox() and obtaining initial value from Firestore

Tags: flutter, checkbox, google-cloud-firestore

I'm no experienced programmer and I could find no guidance, hence this question. I have a working solution but not sure if this is good practice.

I am using the widget Checkbox() in a Form(). Widgets like TextFormField() and DateTimeField() have a parameter called 'initialValue'. Checkbox() does not.

For TextFormField() and DateTimeField() I obtained the initialValue by:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);

    return StreamBuilder<UnitDetails>(
      stream: DatabaseServices(uid: user.userUid, unitUid: widget.unitUid)
          .unitByDocumentID,
      builder: (context, unitDetails) {
        if (!unitDetails.hasData) return Loading();
        return Scaffold(
    etc
```

The Checkbox(value: residentialUnit,) can not have its initial value set inside the builder:. The parameter 'value:' needs to be set true or false before the builder: ie before the value is obtained from Firestore! The way I solved this is by using initState(). An extra call to Firestore and more code for this one input widget.

```
@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Firestore.instance
        .collection("units")
        .document(widget.unitUid)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((snapshot) {
            residentialUnit = snapshot.data['unitResidential'];
        });
}
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve your problem with the following answer (using FormField).

[Checkbox form validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53479942/checkbox-form-validation)

Following is a sample code.

```dart
FormField(
            initialValue: userProfile.agreement,
            builder: (state) {
              return Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Checkbox(
                          activeColor: Colors.blue,
                          value: state.value,
                          onChanged:(value) {
                            setState(() {
                              state.didChange(value);
                            });
                          }
                        ),
                      Expanded(child: Text('Sample checkbox')),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Text(
                    state.errorText ?? '',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Theme.of(context).errorColor,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              );
            },
            validator: (val) {
              print('VAL: $val');
              if (!val) {
                return 'You need to accept terms';
              } else {
                return null;
              }
            },
          )
```

Comment: please can you provide some more context, in case the link ever breaks? thank you!

Comment: I added sample code. I hope this helps you.