# Flutter: Widget communication : ToggleButtons in forms

Tags: flutter, dart

I am currently learning Flutter and making good progress so please bear with me if this is a noob question.

In my application, I created a page to allow logged in users to modify their profiles. In this page, I have a TextFormField (to edit an email) and a ToggleButtons (with two options) to select a profession.

I use a FutureBuilder to retrieve my data from the database in order to pre-fill the TextFormField with the email. I also have the profession of the user. Those parts works well.

But now, when I try my application and I press (onPressed event) the toggleButtons to change the profession, I have a bad behavior. In the onPressed event, I use setState() to refresh the widget so the email field is pre-filled from the database each time I change the profession.

I wanted to know how to manage this case ? What are the best pratices to do that ?
Because I need those values to submit the form after.
I tried to split the widget to isolate the toggleButtons but I cannot send the selected value to the parent widget.

Thank you!

EDIT: add code

That's the code for my profile page :

```
class MyProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MyProfilePageState();
  }
}

class MyProfilePageState extends State<MyProfilePage> {

  final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  final StudentService StudentService = new StudentService();
  final TeacherService TeacherService = new TeacherService();


  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  Teacher _teacher;
  Student _student;

  User user;
  String uid;

  TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    user = auth.currentUser;
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<bool> isProfileRetrieved() async {
    _student = await StudentService.getByUid(user.uid);
    _teacher = await TeacherService.getTeacherByUid(user.uid);
    fillFields();
    return true;
  }

  void fillFields() {
    emailController.text = _teacher == null ? _student.email : _teacher.email;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Theme(
      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(primaryColor: primaryColor),
      child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
              Image.asset(
                'assets/logo.png',
                fit: BoxFit.contain,
                height: 45,
              ),
              Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Text('Teacher Monitoring')),
              Image.asset(
                'assets/logo.png',
                fit: BoxFit.contain,
                height: 45,
              ),
            ]),
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          ),
          body: FutureBuilder(
            future: isProfileRetrieved(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Container(child: Form(
                    key: _formKey,
                    child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                      emailField(),
                      ProfessionWidget(),
                      saveButton()
                    ])));
              } else {
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
            },)),
    );
  }

  

  Widget emailField() {
    return TextFormField(
      controller: emailController,
      decoration: const InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'Enter your email',
          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person),
          labelText: "Email"),
      validator: (String value) {
        if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
          return 'Please enter some text';
        }
        return null;
      },
    );
  }

  Widget saveButton() {
    return SizedBox(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: ElevatedButton.icon(
        icon: Icon(Icons.save_alt),
        label: Text("Save"),
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          primary: primaryColor, // background
          onPrimary: Colors.white, // foreground
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Update Profile')));
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And that's the code to isolate the ToggleButton (it was my last try to fix my issue) :

```
class ProfessionWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  Teacher teacher;
  Student student;

  @override
  _ProfessionWidgetState createState() => _ProfessionWidgetState(teacher, student);
}

class _ProfessionWidgetState extends State<ProfessionWidget> {

  Teacher teacher;
  Student student;

  List<bool> isSelected;

  _ProfessionWidgetState(Teacher teacher, Student student);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    isSelected = [true, false];
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return professionField();
  }


  Future<bool> isProfileRetrieved(teacher, student) async {
    isSelected = [teacher != null, student != null];
    return true;
  }

  Widget professionField() {
    return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
        child: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 7.0),
              child: Text('Profession',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
          ToggleButtons(
            borderColor: Colors.grey,
            selectedColor: Colors.white,
            fillColor: primaryColor,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0, right: 20.0, left: 20.0),
                child: Text(
                  'Teacher',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0, right: 20.0, left: 20.0),
                child: Text(
                  'Student',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                ),
              ),
            ],
            onPressed: (int index) {
              setState(() {
                for (int buttonIndex = 0;
                buttonIndex < isSelected.length;
                buttonIndex++) {
                  isSelected[buttonIndex] = buttonIndex == index;
                  if (buttonIndex == index) {
                    //TODO
                  }
                }
              });
            },
            isSelected: isSelected,
          )
        ]));
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and show your code? It will make it easier for people to see and help you in this way.

Comment: You're right, I added the code :)

Comment: The best approach to this issue is to create custom widget that extends `FormField`. Doing this will allow you to have one `Form` on the top level and multiple statefull widgets deeper in hierarchy. Take a look on this article: https://blog.bam.tech/developer-news/build-a-flutter-form-with-custom-input-types, or this answer for checkbox: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53479942/checkbox-form-validation

Answer (score 0):

From the [FutureBuilder class documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html):

> The future must have been obtained earlier, e.g. during State.initState, State.didUpdateConfig, or State.didChangeDependencies. It must not be created during the State.build or StatelessWidget.build method call when constructing the FutureBuilder. If the future is created at the same time as the FutureBuilder, then every time the FutureBuilder's parent is rebuilt, the asynchronous task will be restarted.

So you need to store this Future's as a variable in your State. With this variable you can supply to the FutureBuilder widget. In this way, you won't need to re-create the Future everytime the screen is rebuilt.

As suggested by the documentation, you can start the future in the initState method:

```
class ProfessionWidget extends StatefulWidget {
[...]
  _ProfessionWidgetState createState() => _ProfessionWidgetState();
}

class _ProfessionWidgetState extends State<ProfessionWidget> {
final Future<bool> storedFuture; //1 - Create the variable.
[...]
  @override
  void initState() {
      super.initState();
      [...]
      storedFuture = isProfileRetrieved(); // 2 - On initState, call the method and keep the return value on the created variable.
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
[...]
    body: FutureBuilder(
            future: storedFuture, // 3 - Pass the stored variable to FutureBuilder.
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
[...]
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Container();
              } else {
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
            });
  }
}
```