# How to bind checkbox form field validator with a button ? (flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I bind a checkbox form field validator with a button like in this picture ?
Thank you in advance!
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checkbox form validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53479942/checkbox-form-validation)

Comment: @eamirho3ein not really :/ I already know how to do that, but how to make the button inactive and then active when the box is checked ?

Comment: simply do this: onClick: _formKey.currentState != null &&
                            _formKey.currentState.validate()
                        ? () {
                          
                          }
                        : null,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DummyScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<DummyScreen> createState() => _DummyScreenState();
}

class _DummyScreenState extends State<DummyScreen> {
  bool isSelected = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            CheckboxListTile(
              value: isSelected,
              onChanged: (val) {
                setState(() {
                  isSelected = !isSelected;
                });
              },
              title: new Text('I agree.', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),),
              controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
              activeColor: Colors.blue,
            ),

            RaisedButton(
              color: isSelected ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
              child: Text('Button'),
              onPressed: () {
                if (isSelected) {
                  ///do what you want 
                }
              }
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]