# Flutter widget not updating?

Tags: flutter, widget, setstate

The delete button in this code seems to leave the checkbox values cached by the row index, i.e. if you have 2 items and delete the 1st, the remaining one will be in the new 1st row and get the checkbox value of the deleted item, not its own. The name in the Text widget works as expected...

```
...mountPoints.map((mp) {
  return TableRow(children: <Widget>[
    const Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(4, 0, 8, 0),
        child: Icon(Icons.computer_outlined)),
    Text(mp.name,
        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
    CheckboxFormField(
        initialValue: mp.sendPosition,
        onSaved: (bool? value) =>
            mp.sendPosition = value ?? false),
    Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 4),
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () => setState(() {
            mountPoints.remove(mp);
          }),
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              backgroundColor: Colors.red),
          child: const Icon(Icons.delete),
        ))
  ]);
})
```

How can I get this checkbox to show the correct value after a delete? The CheckboxFormField here is basically from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57897318/18727185).

Edit: My CheckboxFormField extends Flutter's [FormField](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FormField-class.html), which is a StatefulWidget, and has this comment:

```
/// This widget maintains the current state of the form field, so that updates
/// and validation errors are visually reflected in the UI.
```

... and here's my complete CheckboxFormField:

```
class CheckboxFormField extends FormField<bool> {
  CheckboxFormField(
      {Key? key,
      Widget? title,
      FormFieldSetter<bool>? onSaved,
      FormFieldValidator<bool>? validator,
      bool initialValue = false,
      bool autovalidate = false})
      : super(
            key: key,
            onSaved: onSaved,
            validator: validator,
            initialValue: initialValue,
            builder: (FormFieldState<bool> state) {
              return CheckboxListTile(
                dense: state.hasError,
                title: title,
                value: state.value,
                onChanged: state.didChange,
                subtitle: state.hasError
                    ? Builder(
                        builder: (BuildContext context) => Text(
                          state.errorText!,
                          style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).errorColor),
                        ),
                      )
                    : null,
                controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
              );
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

2 things were needed to fix this:

1. Giving each checkbox a unique key forced them to [refresh](https://alex.domenici.net/archive/how-to-force-a-widget-to-redraw-in-flutter#:%7E:text=The%20solution%20is%20to%20pass,rebuild%20of%20the%20stateful%20widget.).
2. The checkbox value had to be updated on the underlying model object for each change.

Here's the working code (added key and changed 'onSaved' to 'onChanged'):

```
CheckboxFormField(
    key: GlobalKey(),
    initialValue: mp.sendPosition,
    onChanged: (bool? value) =>
        mp.sendPosition = value ?? false)
```

... and the onChanged callback was also added here:

```
class CheckboxFormField extends FormField<bool> {
  CheckboxFormField(
      {Key? key,
      Widget? title,
      FormFieldSetter<bool>? onChanged,
      FormFieldSetter<bool>? onSaved,
      FormFieldValidator<bool>? validator,
      bool initialValue = false,
      bool autovalidate = false})
      : super(
            key: key,
            onSaved: onSaved,
            validator: validator,
            initialValue: initialValue,
            builder: (FormFieldState<bool> state) {
              return CheckboxListTile(
                dense: state.hasError,
                title: title,
                value: state.value,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  if (onChanged != null) {
                    onChanged(value);
                  }
                  state.didChange(value);
                },
                subtitle: state.hasError
                    ? Builder(
                        builder: (BuildContext context) => Text(
                          state.errorText!,
                          style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).errorColor),
                        ),
                      )
                    : null,
                controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
              );
            });
}
```